# How to display arrays declared as vbox/hbox into main window?

Tags: user-interface, lua, iup

I was creating a function that was supposed to display elements into the Main window after a certain function is performed in IUP for Lua.

The problem was that whenever I run the function without arrays for vbox/hbox, the program displays the GUI elements as normal (in this test case, a textbox). I also tested this by having this display on a new window, which also worked. This is the normal code that I used:

```
function wa()
    local txt = {}
    txt[1] = iup.text{
      multiline = "NO",
      padding = "5x5",
      size="100x15",
      scrollbar="Horizontal",
    }
    iup.Append(hrbox, txt[1])
    iup.Map(txt[1])
    iup.Refresh(hrbox)
end
```

But when I ran the code by declaring an array variable as a hbox/vbox into the function, suddenly, the program just won't display the element into the main window, nor at the new window, at all:

```
function wa()
    local txt = {}
    local a = {}
    a[1] = iup.vbox{}
    txt[1] = iup.text{
      multiline = "NO",
      padding = "5x5",
      size="100x15",
      scrollbar="Horizontal",
    }
    iup.Append(a[1], txt[1])
    iup.Map(txt[1])
    iup.Refresh(a[1])
    iup.Append(hrbox, a[1])
    iup.Refresh(hrbox)
end
```

And then the strangest thing is that when I made the hrbox (the box I used to display elements into the main window) into a separate variable altogether, it does not display it in the main window, but it does display in the new window. Here's the code that came afterwards:

```
function wa()
    local txt = {}
    hrbox = iup.hbox{}
    a = {}
    a[1] = iup.vbox{}
    txt[1] = iup.text{
      multiline = "NO",
      padding = "5x5",
      size="100x15",
      scrollbar="Horizontal",
    }
    iup.Append(a[1], txt[1])
    iup.Map(txt[1])
    iup.Refresh(a[1])
    iup.Append(hrbox, a[1])
    iup.Refresh(hrbox)
end
```

How can I make an array variable that is declared as a hbox/vbox element  work so that it can displayed into the main window? I have no idea how to do it, and after going through all the research, I'm essentially stuck.

Any answers and suggestions is appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Would you like to try ```iup.RefreshChildren``` instead?

Comment: @Robert Nope, it did not work. Tried different combinations of iup.RefreshChildren too, but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to create [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):

```
local iup = require("iuplua")

local Button = iup.button{TITLE="Add"}
local hrbox  = iup.vbox{Button}
local Frame  = iup.dialog{hrbox,SIZE="THIRDxTHIRD"}

function wa()
    local txt = {}
    txt[1] = iup.text{
      multiline = "NO",
      padding = "5x5",
      size="100x15",
      scrollbar="Horizontal",
    }
    iup.Append(hrbox, txt[1])
    iup.Map(txt[1])
    iup.Refresh(hrbox)
end

Button.action = function (Ih)
  wa()
end

Frame:show()
iup.MainLoop()
```

So, basically, your code is working properly. Please make sure you declare `hrbox` above the `wa`.

EDIT: I just understand your question finally

You have an issue in this piece of code:

```
function wa()
    local txt = {}
    local a = {}
    a[1] = iup.vbox{}
    txt[1] = iup.text{
      multiline = "NO",
      padding = "5x5",
      size="100x15",
      scrollbar="Horizontal",
    }
    iup.Append(a[1], txt[1])
    iup.Map(txt[1])
    iup.Refresh(a[1])
    iup.Append(hrbox, a[1])
    iup.Refresh(hrbox)
end
```

You actually need to `map` the newly created `hbox`. The children will be automatically mapped in the same time. Calling `refresh` one time is enough.

```
local iup = require("iuplua")

local Button = iup.button{TITLE="Add"}
local hrbox  = iup.vbox{Button}
local Frame  = iup.dialog{hrbox,SIZE="THIRDxTHIRD"}

function wa()
    local txt = {}
    local a = {}
    a[1] = iup.vbox{}
    txt[1] = iup.text{
      multiline = "NO",
      padding = "5x5",
      size="100x15",
      scrollbar="Horizontal",
    }
    iup.Append(a[1], txt[1]) -- Append the text to the new-box
    iup.Append(hrbox, a[1])  -- Append the new-box to the main box
    iup.Map(a[1])            -- Map the new-box and its children
    iup.Refresh(hrbox)       -- Re-calculate the layout
end

Button.action = function (Ih)
  wa()
end

Frame:show()
iup.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I have been banging my head about this problem for days now. Finally, I can finish my program.